# Localized electrostatic-acoustic disturbance

Tags: electrostatics, acoustics, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics

From [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUREX8aFbMs&lc=UgjS7iAyFiZDCXgCoAEC) youtube comment it describes a 'localized electrostatic-acoustic disturbance' as a 'very rapid, sudden static charging of the atmosphere'. I've done some lite searching but haven't found anything that describes this occurrence. What I want to know is if the science behind what's described is sound or not; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly electrostatic [ion-acoustic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_acoustic_wave) in space that have all the same properties as the regular atmospheric sound waves.  The only difference is that the [longitudinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave) oscillations of particles is done by ions and electrons try to eliminate any electric fields created by charge separations.  These are observed with electric field detectors showing modulated sine waves [e.g., [Wilson et al., 2007](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007PhRvL..99d1101W)].

As an aside, electrostatic waves are defined as those that satisfy $\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{E} = 0$, which is different than an [electrostatic discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge).